# Getting a Garbage value on Printing a Page in PHP Desktop

Tags: javascript, php, desktop-application

I am Printing a invoice I filled with input values for print, After generating Final Invoice I am getting Garbage value not in correct format I have shared Below Image. But if I use Php Desktop on external Browser then Printing a page getting correct value.  Thanks in Advance.
[image]

This is My json for php Desktop

```
{
"application": {
    "single_instance_guid": "",
    "dpi_aware": true
},
"debugging": {
    "show_console": false,
    "subprocess_show_console": false,
    "log_level": "DEBUG4",
    "log_file": "debug.log"
},
"main_window": {
    "title": "PHP Desktop",
    "icon": "",
    "default_size": [1024, 768],
    "minimum_size": [800, 600],
    "maximum_size": [0, 0],
    "disable_maximize_button": false,
    "center_on_screen": true,
    "start_maximized": false,
    "start_fullscreen": false,
    "print": true
},
"popup_window": {
    "icon": "",
    "fixed_title": "",
    "center_relative_to_parent": true,
    "default_size": [1024, 768]
},
"web_server": {
    "listen_on": ["127.0.0.1", 0],
    "www_directory": "www",
    "index_files": ["index.html", "index.php"],
    "cgi_interpreter": "php/php-cgi.exe",
    "cgi_extensions": ["php"],
    "cgi_temp_dir": "",
    "404_handler": "/pretty-urls.php"
},
"chrome": {
    "log_file": "debug.log",
    "log_severity": "default",
    "cache_path": "webcache",
    "external_drag": true,
    "external_navigation": true,
    "reload_page_F5": true,
    "devtools_F12": true,
    "remote_debugging_port": 0,
    "command_line_switches": {},
    "enable_downloads": true,
    "context_menu": {
        "enable_menu": true,
        "navigation": true,
        "print": true,
        "view_source": true,
        "open_in_external_browser": true,
        "devtools": true
    }
  }
}
```

The Above json is for PHP Desktop Settings, should I change anything in this json?

Below is my code.

```
function data() {


        var separateDecimal = lclTotal.toString().split('.');
        var paisa = parseInt(separateDecimal[1]);
        var paisaInt = parseInt(paisa);

        $("#txtPrintName").val($("#name").val());
        $("#txtPrintAddress").val($("#address").val());
        $("#txtPrintMobile").val($("#mobile").val());

    }

$(document).on("click", "#print", function (e) {

                // $("#supplier-info, #invoice-no, #txtUniqueNo, #delivery-note, #supplier-reference, #txtSupplierRef, #buyer, #buyer-label, #buyer-label, #txtCusName, #txtAddress, #txtGSTIN").printThis({
                  $("#printCode").printThis({
                    debug: true,               // show the iframe for debugging
                    importCSS: true,            // import page CSS
                    importStyle: true,          // import style tags
                    printContainer: true,       // grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
                    loadCSS:"sale.css", // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
                    pageTitle: "TAX INVOICE",   // add title to print page
                    removeInline: true,         // remove all inline styles from print elements
                    printDelay: 300,            // variable print delay; depending on complexity a higher value may be necessary
                    base: true,                
                    footer: "",                 // prefix to html
                    formValues: true            // preserve input/form values
                });

            });
```

Comment: where which line ?

Comment: ahh, now you do have some code, but probably not the code that is causing the issue (JSON is just configuration data mainly) - the problem is probably with *your code* - I assume you've written some, since you're asking on a coding help site

Comment: That is working on Chrome if I open php Desktop on chrome Browser.

Comment: @Keri You need to share your code for us to be able to tell what the fault is, we are note magicans.

Answer (score 0):

I got Fixed with, I changed version of the PHP Desktop.